# Xcode 6.2 "Invalid Argument" error upon adding folder reference

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, invalid-argument

Every time I add a folder reference to an iOS project and run it on iOS simulator, Xcode fails to run the app on simulator with the error message "invalid argument". While I have read other threads where the error occurred after adding third party SDKs, I get this error even if I follow the steps below:

1. Create a new Xcode project (Objective C), and save it.
2. Select "Add Files to..." from project explorer, and select any folder with files. Select "Create folder references" and leave "Copy files to Project Folder" unchecked, in the dialog box.
3. Try to run the project on any iOS Simulator.

Most likely, this is a problem with my Xcode installation. Has anyone seen this error before? For now, I cannot make the project run again on simulator even by removing the folder reference.

Comment: The trouble is, I've followed your instructions but I don't get the same results. It builds and runs fine for me.

Comment: @matt: I think this should be the normal case, since adding a folder reference is something very common. I hope someone who has had this problem and fixed it will see this post and help out.

Comment: can you try 1.clean build. 2. delete the app in simulator.

Comment: @ Reming Hsu: did not work for my case, but this seems to work in some cases.

Comment: A problem that can't be reproduced is a question that can't be answered.

Comment: Sorry, not enough data to prove that it cannot be reproduced at all :-)

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem when i developer hybrid app.

i am not sure if this works for you.

1. clean build.
2. delete the app in simulator.

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with the following steps. Just leaving it here in case someone else finds it useful:

1. Remove the folder reference that caused the error.
2. Add a Group with the same name as the deleted folder reference.
3. Add the files within the folder to the new group. You can choose to copy the files or otherwise.

This fixed the problem partly, because I still did not get to use a folder reference. But it saved me a lot of time since I could build the project instead of copying everything to a new project.

I am sure this is caused by some problem in my Xcode configuration.